# How to make a infinite scroll, dynamically render a list in Vue js (only visible)

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, vue.js, render

I have a very large array of objects with a lot of data to be rendered by a Vue in components to the DOM, And i guess the best approach to do this is render only the HTML that is going to be visible, for example if each component its 100px height and the component container its 1000px height only render 10 components at a time; until the user scroll down or up, and render and "unrender" the respectives elements in a kind of a FIFO way (first in first out).

So what I'm wondering is: which is the best way to do this?, Could be solved by utilizing one array of 10 objects, and add 100px to the height of the container (placing the container with 50px extra in the bottom and top), so when the user  scrolls in that extra space do the fifo thing, Another solution could be give to each component the capacity of calculation (with a little help of the window object) if is visible and then render itself (with a v-show directive). I don't know.

(Ok this question refers to the dynamic render of a list, not the dynamic load of components either the dynamic components).

Any idea, methodology, standard or technique would be very useful!

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: Array(1000).fill({
      gender: "male",
      name: {
        title: "mr",
        first: "vincent",
        last: "ouellet"
      },
      location: {
        street: "6963 disputed rd",
        city: "brockton",
        state: "yukon",
        postcode: "Z4J 0J2",
        coordinates: {
        latitude: "-60.8550",
        longitude: "-36.0196"
      },
      timezone: {
        offset: "+3:30",
        description: "Tehran"
      }
      },
      email: "vincent.ouellet@example.com",
      login: {
        uuid: "eb9b61f7-fb0b-4731-9a1c-f4b2a7b3b6a9",
        username: "bigpeacock949",
        password: "nyjets",
        salt: "0TdUElhf",
        md5: "0fbc0edb70fda545f8838634f11f4be2",
        sha1: "f83e02d917721a1516b74937841b9c7f75a75d1e",
        sha256: "69e2c04bd4ccb43815b529a7182e1e59b9f788032b8197af54b9b6d3f907b8a3"
      },
      dob: {
        date: "1959-08-27T20:26:03Z",
        age: 59
      },
      registered: {
        date: "2013-10-20T04:51:58Z",
        age: 4
      },
      phone: "647-173-6604",
      cell: "544-306-1457",
      id: {
        name: "",
        value: null
      },
      picture: {
        large: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/13.jpg",
        medium: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/13.jpg",
        thumbnail: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/13.jpg"
      },
      nat: "CA"
      }
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="(user, i) in users">
    <li>
      <image :src="`https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/${i}.jpg`"/>
      <!-- IM THE REAL APLICATION THIS IS A VERY HEAVY UI -->
      <pre>{{user}}</pre>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your current code in a snippet.

Comment: could share some of that data ?

Comment: The snippet its done, I dont kwon whay the data its important, because the question referr to a technique and optamization,.The data in the snippet obviously is not the real data, the thing here its wich is the best way to do it.

Comment: @DiegoMeza sometimes a dummy data help us to test the code ...

Comment: i think it would be hard to implement that using page and components height, but i could give you a solution by paginating the data and showing only 5 or 10 components per page and adding arrows in the top and the bottom to navigate between pages vertically

Comment: Ok, Now i know whats is wrong with my question, this is an "infinite scroll" what im trying to make here, let me change the title !

Comment: I would go for the lazy loading scroll you are talking about (loading items as you scroll to near the bottom), you could add a ref and listen when the user has the ref in the viewport. Regarding the loading of new data, I would use a computed list in the v-for that you trigger by an temporary index of where the user has come in the array (number gets increased by x items loaded in the list)

Comment: @SølveTornøe yeah the computed index sounds good !, but i dont know if a ref is dynamiclly appended into the vue instance when the ref is rendered

Comment: @DiegoMeza Sorry, I don't understand what you wrote. Can you edit the comment more clear? :)

Comment: Lots of examples: [1](https://akryum.github.io/vue-virtual-scroller/#/) [2](https://github.com/ddgll/vue-virtualscroll) [3](https://www.laravel-vuejs.com/auto-virtual-scroll-list-for-vue-js-2/) [4](https://www.vuescript.com/vue-virtual-scroll-list/)  [5](https://www.vuescript.com/vue-virtual-scroller-component/)  [6](https://codepen.io/whitelynx/pen/JGJEoP)

Answer (score 0):

On your created method you can add an eventlistener to find the end of the document.

```
window.onscroll = () => {
    let bottomOfWindow =
      document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight ===
      document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

    if (bottomOfWindow) {
      axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/`).then(response => {
        this.persons.push(response.data.results[0]);
      });
    }
  };
```

Once you get your response your can push to the array in which you are using to iterate.
However when your are using in mobile you need to listen for touch events rather than scroll.

Alternatively I find this plugin https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/ very easy to implement and it takes care of both mobile and desktop events.